# Salesforce Authentication of user

Tags: app, authentication, appexchange

How to make sure the user that installed my salesforce app is registered with my company and purchased subscription.

One way I could think of is I'll email user SHA activation key and when they install app there will be form to enter activation key which could be encrypted and sent to my website end where it will verify if key is in database. Here i don't know how to send post request to my website and how to encrypt key.

What are the other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an application on the app exchange, the license manager application (LMA) provides this functionality and more.

Once you become an ISV partner you can register for an ISV edition - this gives you two free licenses to manage your application sales and licensing.  You can then raise a case to add the LMA to this org.  Once you have tied your application listing to your ISV edition (and thus your LMA instance), lead records will be created when a user downloads/installs your app and a license instance will be created when the user installs your app.

There's more details on license management in the documentation at:

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/lma/index.htm